# ngOptions with dynamic option array from index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use ngRepeat. Within that, I have a select element whos options vary depending on another select. I currently am calling vm.getOperators(filter.keyIndex) in the ng-options, but I get and indefinite loop error from angular. How can I have the following "filterOperator" select options depend on filterColumn select value within an ngRepeat?

html:

```
<div class="form-group row" ng-repeat="filter in vm.filters">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <select class="form-control" name="filterColumn" ng-model="filter.keyIndex">
            <option ng-repeat="key in vm.filterOptions.keys"
                    value="{{ $index }}">
                {{ key.column }}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <select class="form-control" name="filterOperator" ng-model="filter.operator" ng-options="key as value for (key, value) in vm.getOperators(filter.keyIndex)"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4" ng-model="filter.value">
        <input type="text" class="form-control"/>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" ng-show="$last" ng-click="removeFilter($index)">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-1" ng-show="vm.filters.length > 1" ng-click="addFilter()">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller.js:

```
    app.controller('searchCtrl', function() {
    var defaultFilter = {
        keyIndex: "0",
        operator: "",
        value: "",
    };

    var operatorMap = {
        "0": "=",
        "1": "<",
    };

    var vm = this;
    vm.filterOptions = {
        "operators": {
            "type1": ["0", "3"],
            "type2": ["1", "2", "3"]
        },
        "keys": [
            {
                "datatype": "type1",
                "name": "a",
                "column": "col1"
            },
            {
                "datatype": "type1",
                "name": "b",
                "column": "col2"
            },
            {
                "datatype": "type2",
                "name": "c",
                "column": "col3"
            }
        ]
    };
    vm.filters = [];
    //vm.removeFilter = removeFilter;
    //vm.addFilter = addFilter;
    vm.getOperators = getOperators;

    function getOperators(keyIndex) {
        var operators = [];
        var dataType = vm.filterOptions.keys[keyIndex].datatype;

        if (vm.filterOptions.operators[dataType]) {
            angular.forEach(vm.filterOptions.operators[dataType], function (operator, index) {
                var obj = {};
                obj[dataType] = (operatorMap[operator] ? operatorMap[operator] : operator);
                operators.push(obj);
            });
        }
        return operators;
    }

    (function init() {
        // I am actually getting the filterOptions with a REST call, but I've included the data already
        // The following is done after the successful REST call
        // add the first filter
        var filter = defaultFilter;
        filter.operator = Object.keys(getOperators(filter.keyIndex))[0];
        vm.filters.push(filter);
    }).call();
});
```

Here's a plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/yGyvwThuWWnNph72OAT0

Comment: can you provide us a plunker with your REST service data ?

Comment: I've added a plunker. I also removed the REST call, since I had already added the data object. In my app, I'll fetch the object via REST however

Comment: That error is because of digest cycle issue caused by calling your getOperators() function.But seriously that is some heavy looping you have used in calling function.Couldn't understand what are you trying achieve in display

Comment: the looping is more to transform the data a bit. My main goal is to populate the filterOperator select with values dependant on the filterColumn select value. Thus when the filterColumn is changed, I need to change the options for the filterOperator select. To get the option values, I need to 1. look at the selected column's datatype. 2. display the appropriate operators for the given datatype. The getOperators function contains that logic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I figured this out.

First, don't generate an array in the getOperators method. You can return and array that is already defined, but you can't generate a new array here. This leads to an indefinite loop as angular detects a change and call the getOperators method again.

So what I did was...

1. after the data was fetched from the REST service, I call a function "transformOperators". This implements the looping I was doing in "getOperators" and stores this "transformed data" in a class level object.
2. in "getOperators" I simply do an object lookup and return the results.